# How to set height and constraint dynamically in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-autolayout

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to set constraint on custom tableview. I am using two label as in the image

[image]

But also after the constraint it is giving me gap

[image]

I found a solution but not able to understand and apply here.

```
//Assign Table View Hight...
closetableview.estimatedRowHeight = 80;//the estimatedRowHeight but if is more this autoincremented with autolayout
closetableview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
[closetableview setNeedsLayout];
[closetableview layoutIfNeeded];
closetableview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0) ;

closetableview.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

I have already write code like this in viewDidLoad.

Comment: which gap occurs issue ?

Comment: @KKRocks As you see in the image gap between test and the bradbys text.

Comment: tblViewDetail.estimatedRowHeight = 100;
  tblViewDetail.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension; add this lines in viewDidLoad and set proper constraint .

Comment: set constraint as below :http://stackoverflow.com/a/38064420/3901620

Comment: muja just set label constrain 3 side and hight greater then equal to both label and remove space between it and your tableview set row hight UItableviewautomaticdimension your problem solve

Comment: @Muju did you got your solution ?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya Yes I got the solution.Its constraint problem.